# Windows Server 2008 softwares sharing usage

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory, shared-folders

Ok, I just install the Windows 2008. In here, I would like to use Win Server 2008 with delphi, eclipse, and other softwares installed.

And now, I would like to ask several questions.

1. Is it possible for the clients / workstations with win XP/7 only and no other softwares to be login with domain user n password into server and use the installed programs on server ?
2. If can, is it possible for every users who logged in to the server via domain to modif and install plugin the servers softwares (delphi, eclipse, and other softwares installed)  ? 
   PS: Every user has different style of installed plug in.
3. If can, could you please provide me the step by step solution for the active directory setting.

Thanks before ^^

Comment: Just because it states server does not mean you can connect and use the software on it as if the were working on their own machines. To me it sounds like what you actually want is a Citrix XenApp or XenDesktop server. http://www.citrix.com/English/ps2/products/product.asp?contentID=1857200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for the clients / workstations with win XP/7 only and no other softwares to be login with domain user n password into
>   server and use the installed programs on server ?

Yes with [Group Policy](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8739/restrict-users-to-run-only-specified-programs-in-windows-7/) (the link shows how to do the local group policy for the machine but this can be set up with active directory also using almost the same steps) you can set it so the user can only access a specified list of programs on the server.

> If can, is it possible for every users who logged in to the server via domain to modif and install plugin the servers softwares (delphi,
>   eclipse, and other softwares installed) ? PS: Every user has different
>   style of installed plug in.

Only if the software you are trying to use supports setting up like this. Some things like Eclipse can be installed in the user's home directory so each user will have their own copy to use each with it's own plugins.

> If can, could you please provide me the step by step solution for the active directory setting.

Unfortunately no, however hopefully I gave you points in the right direction though. If you get hung up on a step after trying on your own feel free to come back and ask on how to solve your specific problem in a new question.

Comment: Ok, what do you mean with : "Some things like Eclipse can be installed in the user's home directory so each user will have their own copy to use each with it's own plugins."

Comment: Ok, what do you mean with : "Some things like Eclipse can be installed in the user's home directory so each user will have their own copy to use each with it's own plugins."

Comment: Eclipse does not need to be "installed" you just unzip it and run, each user will need to have their own copy of Eclipse in a folder that is not shared with the other users. "The user's home directory" is a directory that is accessible to the user and no one else. Things like "My Documents" and your desktop are stored as folders underneath the home directory (For example: `C:\Users\schamberlain` would be my home directory and `C:\Users\SCiang` would be your home directory if we where using the same computer). All a user needs to do is unzip Eclipse under `C:\Users\username\Eclipse`

Comment: In that case, it's more like a portable software... Does it works for softwares with capability like "install it for me only or everyone" ? Will it be able to works like eclips do ?

Comment: If the program stores things in a user independent way (and if it has that prompt it should) then each user can have his own settings.

Comment: IC... Does this works on Microsoft office ? Eg : some user has their own style for words / excel GUI. And some user has their own setting for outlook. (All stored in one single server)

Comment: No idea, but likely, the only thing to do is try it and see what happens.

Comment: LoL... OK, thanks for the help ^^ BTW I post another question at : http://superuser.com/questions/454876/windows-server-2008-cpu-load-balancing