# Windows server 2008 CPU load balancing

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, memory-management, load-balancer

I have a Windows server 2008 CPU and Active Directory installed. Some how with lot of users and compiling process and many things, the CPU load rise too much and makes the server goes slow.

What is in my mind is I want to share my server CPU/Memory load into other PC. Where the server could share its CPU/memory load into another PC via network. It is more like that I need a with "CPU load balancing" capability (not network load balancing).

Anybody has the idea how to do this in Windows Server 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is exactly what tools like the [Remote Desktop Connection Broker](https://web.archive.org/web/20150629143125/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rds/archive/2010/10/15/remote-desktop-connection-broker-scalability-testing-results.aspx) and [Persional Virtual Desktops](https://web.archive.org/web/20150705004155/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rds/archive/2009/11/16/personal-virtual-desktops.aspx) where designed to do. The user connects to one of several servers when they initiate a remote desktop connection. This allows you to have more users than one server can handle.

This does not "Share CPU" like you described but it allows you to have a single computer not get overloaded by distributing the users across several computers invisibly to the end user.

I reccomend you buy the book [Windows Server® 2008 R2 Remote Desktop Services Resource Kit](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/windows-server-2008/9780735651241/). I used it when I was first starting to do some advanced things with Remote Desktop and it helped a lot.

I would recommend asking further questions on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) has these questions are above the "Super User" scope and getting in to the IT professional scope.

Comment: Ok, should I copy-paste this question on Server Fault ?

Comment: No, Flag your question to a moderator and they can move it.

Comment: Ok, done. Next what should I do ?

Comment: [sf] moderators [rejected](http://superuser.com/posts/454876/revisions) the [migration](http://serverfault.com/questions/412207/windows-server-2008-cpu-load-balancing), fyi.

Comment: @Sathya can we get it re-opened back here seance it is not a server fault question after all?